# Using Libcurl to send very large strings to a server using REST API?

Tags: c++, http, rest, networking, libcurl

I am trying to send very large strings (up to 16GB worth) to a cloud server (similar to AWS) for storage as a file using the REST API.  I would like to stream the string in smaller chunks to the server, and the string chunks will be generated on-the-fly.  From what I can tell, setting the Transfer Encoding to "chunked" will help me do just that.  I have started writing a C++ program to do this, using the libcurl library.  Here is a relevant snippet with simplified test strings:

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: text/plain");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: binary/octet-stream");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.1:8080/namespace/test/test");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "5/r/nHELLO/r/n");
curl_res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "3/r/nBYE/r/n");
curl_res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "0/r/n");
curl_res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

From what I understand about chunked transfers, each chunk should begin with the size of the string expressed as a hexadecimal number, followed by the actual string.  When a zero is encountered for the size, then the server knows that the transfer is complete  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).  However, when I look at the contents of the file after I execute the above, all I see is '0' instead of 'HELLOBYE'.  So not only is it overwriting the file at each chunk transfer, it is also interpreting the size of the string as part of the string.

So my question boils down to:

1. How can I get it to interpret the first part of my chunk transfers as the size of the string?
2. How can I get it to "concatenate" sequential chunks transfers?

Comment: You should not call `easy_perform` multiples times, and let libcurl prepare the `POST` data (libcurl handles internally the ability to append the data in chunks). I'd recommend you to refer to the [post-callback.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html) exemple that illustrates chunked transfer encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done with libcurl, but you should let libcurl do the entire request and you should just feed it the data to send little by little. The [post-callback.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html) example on the curl web site is almost exactly what you're asking for.

The key is to set the correct header and then use the read callback.

Answer (score 0):

Rarify. I don't know whether my answer will resolve your issue. But please try this and share the result you got after change.

Add following configuration to the curl:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING, 0);
```

The reason to do so is libcurl will decode the chunks for you by default.

Maybe a better way to let me help you more is posting your network headers and data captured by wireshark? Otherwise is really hard to debug network programming.

On the other hand, I think the main issue is on the libcurl. Hence, I strongly advise you go to register one curl mail list under [curl library mail listing](http://cool.haxx.se/mailman/listinfo/curl-library) so that you can broadcast your query to those experts. It will benefit you a lot.